# Delete a SQL table record using C# & SQL WHERE clause

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to delete a SQL table record using C#. I already tried the below mentioned code snippet but it didn't work. However the message is showing 'Data Record Deleted!' as it should it be. I can't find an issue in the statement also.

```
private void delemp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if(MessageBox.Show("do you really want to delete this","Deleting ", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            EMP.DELETEMP(this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show("deleting Seccussfully","Deleting ");
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = EMP.GET_ALL_EMP();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Deleting Canceled ");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
    }            
}
```

and this is the class

```
public void DELETEMP(string ID)
{
        DAL.dataaccesslayer DAL = new DAL.dataaccesslayer();
        DAL.open();
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        param[0].Value = ID;
        DAL.executcommand("DELETEMP", param);
        DAL.close();
}
```

Comment: For one thing, `DELETEMP` isn't a class, it's a method. For another, we can't see where the message "Data Record Deleted!" comes from because in your code the messages are in Arabic. Respectfully, please translate the messages, edit your post, and put English versions of the messages there so we can help you better.

Comment: i am sorry for this mistake . i hope you can help me with this . Post Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EMP.DELETEMP()` doesn't return a result of any kind so it will be impossible for you to know whether the record was actually deleted or not. As long as `EMP.DELETEMP()` doesn't throw an exception, which it might not, your code will always display the "deleting Seccussfully" message.

So, most likely `EMP.DELETEMP()` isn't actually deleting anything. To fix this, you are going to need to figure out why. It looks like there is maybe a stored procedure in the database called `DELETEMP` that takes an ID (integer?) parameter. Have you tested this stored procedure?

Also, we are assuming that `DAL` works as intended. I do not recognize this. It is possibly not fully legitimate because the method you are calling is `DAL.executcommand()` which isn't even spelled correctly.

Comment: public void DELETEMP(string ID)
        {
            DAL.dataaccesslayer DAL = new DAL.dataaccesslayer();
            DAL.open();
            SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];
            param[0] = new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            param[0].Value = ID;
            DAL.ExecuteCommand("DELETEMP", param);
            DAL.close();
        }

Comment: evey things work good the insert and update . i have tried tested this stored procedure its working good

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't tell if you are saying the problem is solved or not.